# How can I move my current session from GNU screen to tmux?

Tags: tmux, gnu-screen, migration, irssi

My IRC client, `irssi`, is currently active inside a GNU `screen` session.
In hindsight, I wish that I'd have used `tmux` instead of GNU `screen`.
How can I migrate the active process (or session) from GNU `screen` to `tmux`?

Comment: Adding as a comment since this migrates to `tmux`, but doesn't actually migrate from `screen` as asked.  [1] * Press Ctrl-A, then d (detach `screen`) [2] Run `tmux` [3] Run: `screen -R -x` [4] Enjoy `tmux`.  Don't press Ctrl-A.  Ignore `screen`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `reptyr`.

This [other answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1293299/432690) provides useful details. It is about migrating an outside process into `screen`/`tmux`, but I have just tested on my Debian 9 and successfully migrated `htop` *from* `screen` to `tmux`.

After finding the PID of `htop`, I invoked `reptyr PID` from a shell inside `tmux`. I then went back to `screen` and terminated it totally; this included exiting the shell that had started `htop`. `htop` did survive attached to a tty provided by `tmux`. I believe your `irssi` will survive as well.

`exec reptyr PID` or `tmux new-window 'reptyr PID'` would also work, although there would be no shell between the tmux server and `reptyr`. In case of a simple `reptyr PID` invoked in an interactive shell, the shell keeps running and you will get back to it after the captured process terminates eventually.

Comment: @Attie `ptrace_scope=0` is not the only option. I expanded the linked answer.

Answer (score 0):

Migrating an active session from `screen` to `tmux` is unfortunately not possible today as the functionality to do so has not been developed. They are completely different applications and don't support managing each other's sessions - that may change in future, but it's not possible as of April 2016.

What I'd suggest as a workaround is attaching to your existing `irssi` screen session within a `tmux` window. In other words, do a `screen -r` from within one of your `tmux` windows. You may have some conflicts if their keybindings clash (for example if you've remapped your `tmux` hotkey to be <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd>, the screen default), but you can at least just use one application and not two.

Comment: Not possible, or not supported?  What technical limitation prevents the possibility of making the required changes in RAM?

Comment: Well, yes you're right. There's nothing making it impossible - `tmux` and/or `screen` could add support for managing the other's sessions. I'll amend my answer to make it a bit clear - it's not possible *today* as the support isn't there. But that may, of course, change at some point...

Comment: Your attempt at making "not possible" more clear has been successful, yet the current phrasing still feels wrong.  You may want to look up the definition of "possible", and contrast that to some other words or phrases, such as "supported option", "a convenient process/procedure", "currently implemented feature", "available usable functionality", etc.  These are open source programs, and statements like "not possible" may dissuade novice coders from even considering the task of adding such functionality.

Comment: *shrug* I think "possible today" makes it fairly clear. Feel free to rewrite my answer if you're still unhappy...